# En veux-tu? En voilà/En v’là!

Tags: usage, oral, contractions

Je lisais hier dans un roman l’expression *« en veux-tu, en voilà »*, qui ne pose pas vraiment de question en dépit de la tournure interrogative qu’elle contient.

En lisant, j’ai senti une espèce de malaise, et ai finalement mis le doigt sur le bobo : je ne crois pas dans ma vie, hors l’écriture ou les discours peu naturels *(radio, télé, personnes parlant trop lentement afin de mieux s’écouter, ...)*, avoir entendu autre chose qu’***en veux-tu, en v’là***.

Je viens du Québec, je voyage peu en Francophonie, et une bonne moitié de mes communications se passe en anglais avec des anglophones, mais demeure curieux de savoir si la forme longue ***en voilà*** existe bien quelque part dans le vrai usage oral, ou si elle se cantonne à peu près dans les livres et chez ceux qui veulent trop bien parler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne pense jamais avoir entendu ***en veux-tu, en v'là*** en France, peut-être à cause du décalage de registre entre ***en veux-tu*** qui est plutôt formel alors qu'***en v'là*** est familier.

C'est donc toujours:

> en veux-tu, en voilà.

Une version familière pourrait être :

> t'en veux, en v'là

mais ce n'est plus la locution attendue.

[**Wikipedia**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_veux-tu_en_voil%C3%A0) indique que ***en veux-tu, en v'là*** est une variante que l'on rencontre en français canadien.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je suis surpris d'apprendre que *en veux-tu* est senti comme formel en France (sauf erreur, ce n'est pas le cas au Québec). *V'là* est-il communément entendu chez vous?

Comment: *V'là* est peut-être un peu désuet mais s'entend quand même, dans un registre familier, dans *en v'là deux*, *le v'là*, *les v'là*, *te v'là*...

Comment: Il y aussi l'expression consacrée *22, v'là les flics* (la connait-on au Québec ?).

Comment: @Greg Il y a toujours eu le tome 22 de la série Boule et Bill, appréciée des enfants et parents de part et d’autre de l’Atlantique, intitulé ***22! v’là Boule et Bill!***, et de manière plus ennuyante ***Les v’là!*** depuis la réorganisation des premiers tomes en moins de pages par album, ce qui relégua cet album au titre ingénieux au #25 (quelle horreur!).

Comment: Tel que je l'ai mentionné ci-dessus, je suis surpris de certains aspects linguistiques mentionnés dans votre réponse, mais il demeure au final que vous suppléez exactement la réponse à la question: **en veux-tu en voilà** existe à l'oral, et est même à peu près l'unique prononciation de l'expression ailleurs qu'au Québec. Merci.